# Azure Request-Response Session Timeout handling

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We are using the azure service bus to facilitate the parallel processing of messages through workers listening to a queue.

First an aggregated message is received and then this message is split in thousands of individual messages which are posted through a request-response pattern since we need to know when all messages have been completed to run a separate process.

Our issue is that the request-response method has a timeout which is causing the following issue:

Lets say we post 1000 messages to be processed and there is only one worker listening. Messages left in the queue after the timeout expiration are discarded which is something that we do not want. If we set the expiry time to a large value that will guarantee that all messages will be processed then we run the risk of a message failing and having to wait the timeout to understand that something has gone wrong.

Is there a way to dynamically change the expiration of a single message in a request-response scenario or any other pattern that we should consider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You got the things wrong, The Time to live of an azure service bus message https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.timetolive.aspx It is the time on which the message will be on the queue if it is consumed or not.

This it is not the timeout, if you post a message with this larger time to live the message will stay on the queue for a long time but if you fail to consume you should warn the other end that you failed to consume this message.

You can do this using another queue and putting another message on this other queue with the message id that failed and the error.

This is an asynchronous process so you should not be holding requests based on that but work with the asynchronous nature of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I did not explain the problem well enough. I am not referring to the TTL of a message. Azure Bus supports sessions that are used to correlate a request with a response. A request is made in one queue and a response is provided on another queue. Here is a sample [Sample from MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Brokered-Messaging-Request-0ce8fcaf). I am referring to the actual timeour property that needs to be provided when a session is created. If this timeout is reached and no processor has picked up the message then the message response will never be picked up.

Comment: My mistake was mentioning the deadletter queue which you are right will use the TTL of the queue.

Comment: Did you read my comment below your answer? This question concerns an orchestrated process that needs to know when all messages have been processed.